# Directory structure result as a json from backend

Tags: java, spring-boot, directory

Hi in my application I have a requirement for list the directory structure for a given path using java backend and front-end angularjs so from front end side if I give the following json it will display the folder structure front end

```
{ folders: [
            { name: 'Folder 1', files: [{ name: 'File 1.jpg' }, { name: 'File 2.png' }], folders: [
                { name: 'Subfolder 1', files: [{ name: 'Subfile 1.txt' }] },
                { name: 'Subfolder 2' },
                { name: 'Subfolder 3' }
            ]},
            { name: 'Folder 2' }
        ], files: [{ name: 'File 1.gif' }, { name: 'File 2.gif' }]}
```

So now i have to get the same like this json from Backend usinng java and spring boot i tried different ways but i didnt get the solution .So can any one please help me out to acheive this.Thanks

Sample code i have tried following code its returning only first folder name as result

```
Map<String, Object> dirSt = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
        Map<String, String> folders = new HashMap<String, String>();
        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        File[] firstLevelFiles = dir.listFiles();
        if (firstLevelFiles != null && firstLevelFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File aFile : firstLevelFiles) {
                /*for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                    System.out.print("\t");
                }*/
                System.out.println(level);
                dirSt = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
                    folders = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    System.out.println("[" + aFile.getName() + "]");
                    folders.put("name",aFile.getName());
                    dirSt.put("folders",folders);
                    listDirectory(aFile.getAbsolutePath(), level + 1);
                    return dirSt;
                } else {
                    dirSt.put("name",aFile.getName());
                    System.out.println(aFile.getName());
                    return dirSt;
                }
            }
        }
        return dirSt;
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Using a simple pojo, a json mapper like Jackson and the built-in file apis that shouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: I have tried the recursive method and using java8 file walk but I am not able to get this out please help me

Comment: Show some code and where exactly you failed (and how) and we might be able to provide suggestions.

Comment: @Thomas I have edited some code can you please have look thanks

Comment: Your code looks like you're on the right track and like it's meant to be recursive but the implementation isn't correct. Try to step through it with a debugger to see what it does. One obvious problem: you're returning `dirSt` from within your loop which means you'd only check the first element and stop there - which is very likely not what you want. Additionally, you're only using maps but those are mapped to json objects only thus you can't get the lists that `folders` and `files` should represent.

Answer (score 1):

From your question and the comments it looks like you want to use maps and lists only and convert those to JSON. Since you didn't provide any information on how you're doing the actual JSON mapping I'll leave it for now and concentrate on the creation of the Java structures only.

Since it's your task I won't provide any compilable code but some pseudo code to give you an idea of what you should do.

First, let's look at some basics:

- JSON mappers will normally map Java maps to JSON objects.
- To get JSON arrays/lists you'll need to use arrays or lists in Java as well.
- Listing a file tree will need recursive operations.

With that information your recursive method could look like this (keep in mind that this is pseudo code and thus I won't look up all the correct method names and parameters):

```
public Map<String, Object> listDirectory( File dir ) {
  File[] content = dir.list(); 

  List<File> files = new LinkedList<>();
  List<Map<String, Object>> folders = new LinkedList<>();

  for( File f : content ) {
    if( f.isDirectory() ) {
      Map<String, Object> subList = listDirectory( f );
      folders.add( subList );
    } else {
      files.add( f );
    }
  }

  Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
  result.put( "folders", folders );
  result.put( "files", files );
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Thoams i'll try out this